# Passing multiple mime types as type in document picker expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

How can i pass multiple types as type in `document picker expo`. I want to restrict that user can only choose pdf and images as files.

can i do like this :

```
const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
    type: ['image/*','application/pdf']
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `type` property is described as `string|Array<string>` I believe yes, you can pass `['image/*','application/pdf']` there.

https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker#options

Comment: i'm using https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/document-picker/ and in `type` property is described as `string`, is it always available to do `['image/*','application/pdf']`

Comment: Yeah, looking at the source code of that module I'm afraid you can only pass a string there...